# R shiny: send data to Firebase

Tags: r, firebase, shiny, shinyjs

I would like to send some data to Firebase using shiny, this is a simplified version of my `app.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

callFB <- "shinyjs.FB = function(){
    var config = {
        apiKey: 'my_apiKey',
        databaseURL: 'my_databaseURL'
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var database = firebase.database();
    var id = database.ref('test').push().key;

    var myData = 'hello';

    console.log(id); // OK
    console.log(myData); // OK
    console.log(database); // OK

    database.ref('test/' + id + '/').update({myData}).then(function() {
        console.log('myData sent!');
    }); // ERROR
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        tags$head(tags$script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js")),
        tags$head(tags$script(src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase.js")),
        useShinyjs(),
        extendShinyjs(text = callFB),
        textOutput("sendFB")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$datauri <- renderText({
        js$FB()
        return("data sent")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This however return an error:

```
> runApp()
Error: shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript code provided.
```

I already tested the js code in a normal html file and it works just fine. The line that seems to cause the error is the last one `database.ref...`

Any idea what may be causing this error? Is there an other way to handle this?

**Edit**

For some unknown reason this works:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

callFB <- "shinyjs.FB = function(){
    var config = {
        apiKey: 'my_apiKey',
        databaseURL: 'my_databaseURL'
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var database = firebase.database();
    var id = database.ref('test').push().key;

    var myData = 'hello';

    database.ref('test/' + id + '/').update({myData}).then(function() {
        console.log('myData sent!');
    });
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        tags$head(tags$script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js")),
        tags$head(tags$script(src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase.js")),
        useShinyjs(),
        textOutput("sendFB")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$datauri <- renderText({
        runjs(callFB)
        return("data sent")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: in your example that doesn't work you're calling `js$FB()` - what's `FB()` ?

Comment: `FB` comes from `shinyjs.FB`, it's basically the way the function is called. There's an other example provided here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyjs/vignettes/shinyjs-extend.html